# ArrayList does not want to persist on AppEngine HR database, how to fix it?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I am trying to persist and ArrayList, but it does not work. Everything
is great locally [M/S db], but when I deploy it [HR] then objects do
not persist. Any ideas why? It's really weird and I cannot find any
solution.

I use JDO with DataNucleus and  Guice for injections, here is required code:

```
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", serialized="true")
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>> colonisations = new
ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>>();
```

at User class

Another class, that tries to persist the data:

```
@Inject
public Repository<User> userRepo;

...
...
MySession.get().getUser().getColonisations().add(colonisation);
...
...
Colonisation.this.userRepo.persist(MySession.get().getUser());
```

The only hint I am getting from logs is:

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl close: Outstanding nontx update
being committed to datastore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the field dirty solves the issue, so DataNucleus sees that it's been changed.

```
JDOHelper.makeDirty(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the currentTransaction while persisting?

I wish I had more info about this, but I had a similar problem, while persisting and retrieving from datanucleus using JDO in GAE, and I figured out that while I was using

```
persistenceManager.currentTransaction().begin();
// persist and/or retrieve
persistenceManager.currentTransaction().commit();
```

I didn't have any more problems.

I hope I 've helped a bit.

Comment: BTW, I fixed it by making my lists dirty after doing any changes.